# Get the unique download link on Openload

Tags: javascript, php, android, curl, video

I plan to make an Android mobile video streaming application. The videos are mostly hosted by Openload.co, so that the videos can open in a player on the mobile one must succeed in recovering the direct link of the video Openload. I need to code this in PHP. I tried to retrieve that in the source code of the page with a file_get_contents or a Curl, but nothing does. The file_get_contents and Curl do not load the page and its scripts before retrieving the source code. Except that the link of the video is a unique link. It changes every time the page is refreshed. The link is generated by javascript code.

An example, here is the embed link of the video: https://openload.co/embed/z_wuuTTJSCg/

In the source code via inspect the item (or developer console I don't know, on your browser), you can see the line:

In this line is the id, date , IP and a token. (Example: z_wuuTTJSCg~1496728099~149.91.0.0~rIj0zw9c)

What is in this line is added to this link: https://openload.co/stream/ (example: openload.co/z_wuuTTJSCg~1496728099~149.91.0.0~rIj0zw9c)

and it's work like that.

If you look at the source code of this page directly with "view-source:" you will see that in the line designate there will be marked "HERE IS THE LINK".

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
'use strict';
alert("Subtitle File URL: "+suburl);
alert("Video File URL: https://openload.co/stream/"+document.getElementById("streamurl").innerHTML+"?mime=true");
})();
```

This is a function that runs after the OpenLoad page has gotten all the variables sorted out for you so you can just hotlink the video

If your application does not run the web page and only retrieves it (like cURL) the script that creates the valid token is on line 163 of the source code, right after script element
`<script src="/assets/js/video-js/video.js.ol8.js"></script>`.
However it will require a large amount of time to understand how it is created and be able to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Most easiest way to get openload link, just use youtube-dl cause you can't done that with PHP & JS