# How to access embedded openload iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get direct download links from embedded openload links (example: https://openload.co/embed/CoKeagPRpQg/). The result might look something like this: https://openload.co/stream/CoKeagPRpQg~1527355595~2a02:120b::~J-XBN0SR?mime=true. If you navigate to the embed link and run

```
document.querySelector("#mediaspace_wrapper > div:last-child > p:last-child")
```

from the developer console, the essential data for the stream link is returned. When I tried to implement this on an embedded video on my private site, I got an error for cross site scripting, which is understandable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Proflix</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="video" src="https://openload.co/embed/CoKeagPRpQg/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true"
        webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I stumbled across [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/openload-video-only/leallakffbiflfgpmamdgcojddnbfdgo?hl=en) chrome extension, which with JavaScript alone can enter the iframe ([Demo](https://youtu.be/TjnQuEwo28U)). This really puzzles me. I contacted the developer and he told me his extention was based on [this](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/17665-openload/code) script. But it didn't work from the developer console. My question is: How can JavaScript enter a foreign iframe in this example and how can I replicate it?

Related:

[Get the unique download link on Openload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362943/get-the-unique-download-link-on-openload)

[Get stream URL from openload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643330/get-stream-url-from-openload?s=1|75.9996)

Comment: The extension's [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) runs inside the iframe directly. It doesn't "enter" the iframe.

Comment: So can I replicate this with pure JavaScript or does this only work for chrome extensions?

Comment: Content script is an extension thing. It's still pure JS.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not very familiar with chrome extensions. In short: Can I get the capabilities from this extension working on my web page without the extension installed?

Comment: No, only extensions can run content scripts.